# Does the comma operator odr-use its arguments?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

According to the [odr-use defintion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), an object is odr-used if a reference is bound to it. This is why f makes S::x odr-used I believe. What I can not understand is how is that any different from the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) which also binds its arguments to reference parameters

```
struct S {
    static const int x = 0; // static data member
    // a definition outside of class is required if it is odr-used
};
const int& f(const int& r);

int n = b ? (1, S::x) // S::x is not odr-used here
          : f(S::x);  // S::x is odr-used here: a definition is required
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are just *examples* for how an *overloaded comma operator* might be defined in a class. It's the usage of such an overload that would necessarily trigger odr-use, when you bind to the arguments.

That usage hasn't been written into your program, nor has an operator overload at all for that matter.

You're just using [the built-in comma operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma).

(A more interesting question might be whether the right-most operand to this operator is still odr-used, because from [the wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) it looks to me like it is! Do remember that an odr-use violation isn't required to generate a build error, and in certain situations it won't.).

I would argue that the cppreference page is possibly a little unclear in that regard.

Comment: [basic.def.odr]/4 is hard to parse but ok maybe that's an exemption for a case like this

Answer (score 2):

The built-in comma does not bind its operands to anything.

Overloaded commas do, but overloaded operators are just functions with a funny spelling.

Comment: On a question tagged language-lawyer, I'd expect a quote from an authoritative source.

Comment: A quote for which claim, exactly?